# Add space from 3TB unto 4TB using raid, how?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning, raid, software-raid

I would like to expand my 4 TB drive by adding on drive space from my 3 TB drive.  I assume this is possible in a raid configuration by resizing the partion on the 3 TB to free space then using windows to  reconfigure the space to bee seen as extra space on the 4TB drive via raid.  I have information I cannot backup (nowhere to back up to hence the space issue) and would like to just add the space on without the need to format and not as a folder but just empty space.  Any Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which RAID configuration did you plan on using?  RAID isn't really designed to combine 2 separate disk that are different sizes to treat them as a single drive.

Comment: Doing this without backups is risky. I strongly suggest either backups (and test those!) or just mounting the second drive under a folder.

Comment: Could use `dynamic disks` to accomplish this, but I don't recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done, but I have to give the following warning first:

I highly recommend you not do this unless you value the educational experience over the security of your personal data.  All it will do for you is make one drive a little bugger and the other a little smaller.  It does not offer any performance advantages but has some serious drawbacks.

The setup you are talking about is JBOD, not RAID; the difference being that JBOD does not provide redundancy in the event of a hardware failure.  This is **NOT** an effective backup solution.  It actually **increases** your risk because if one of the drives fails, you can lose the data on BOTH drives.  As an added bonus, having the data distributed across multiple drives makes it exponentially harder to recover if you ever needed to.

---

That being said, I have to make the following assumptions about your setup (since you did provide give any details).

- You are not using a hardware-assisted RAID controller (i.e. RAID is OFF in your BIOS).  If you are, then this whole post is irrelevant and you can stop reading now (the warnings above still apply though).  The only way you can expand a hardware-assisted RAID is if the controller specifically supports it (most integrated RAID solutions do not).
- Windows must be installed to the drive you intend to shrink, not the one you intend to expand.  Windows cannot boot from a dynamic volume that spans multiple physical disks without hardware support.
- Both disks must be internal.  You cannot create a JBOD or RAID on a USB drive.

---

Now with all that out of the way, here's how you can do this:

1. Defrag your C: drive.  Windows will not move files to accommodate the new partition size.
2. Within Disk Management, right-click your C: drive on the partition map and select "Shrink Volume..." and pick the new size.
3. Right-click Disk 0 on the partition map and select "Convert to Dynamic Disk..."
4. Do the same thing for the other hard drive (probably Disk 1), converting it to a Dynamic Disk as well.
5. Right-click the partition on Disk 1 and choose "Extend Volume...".  Select all of the free space from Disk 0 and hit OK.

You now have two disks in a JBOD setup.